# "in" keyword before parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#, just question on "in" keyword, I understand how 'out' works, but why do we need 'in' as

```
delegate TResult Func <in T, out TResult> (T arg);
```

is it the same as:

```
delegate TResult Func <T, out TResult> (T arg);
```

Comment: Please look up `in (Generic Modifier) C#` in google, the documentation will be one of the first results

Comment: For generic type parameters, the in keyword specifies that the type parameter is contravariant. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier

Comment: `in` parameters are read-only inside the method.  And, they can’t be modified further. You can only refer them.